# How can i remove empty/null items from angularjs select dropdown?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```js
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.mail_notifications = [
        {
            "key": "all",
            "value": "For any event on all my projects"
        },
        {
            "key": "selected",
            "value": "For any event on the selected projects only..."
        },
        {
            "key": "only_my_events",
            "value": ""
        },
        {
            "key": "only_assigned",
            "value": "Only for things I am assigned to"
        },
        {
            "key": "only_owner",
            "value": ""
        },
        {
            "key": "none",
            "value": "No events"
        }
    ];
    $scope.mail_notification = 'all';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl">        
<select ng-model="mail_notification" ng-options="c.key as c.value for c in mail_notifications"></select>
</div>
</div>
```

I have a below Fiddle link for reference.

https://jsfiddle.net/maayuresh/mjugfLr0/1/

In above Fiddle , I have json object named mail_notifications.
In this some properties are empty , null like this -> ""

This null values are getting displayed in select dropdown list.

My aim is to remove that from the select dropdown.
How can i achive that ?

Comment: why don't you write a condition `if(null){do something}`

Answer (score 0):

FYI,

> This null values are getting displayed in select dropdown list.

`null` is not equivalent to `""` (empty string)

To filter the item with `value` is not an empty string:

```js
$scope.mail_notifications = $scope.mail_notifications.filter(x => x["value"] != "");
```

You may also work with filtering the item with value is a [truthy value](https://262.ecma-international.org/5.1/#sec-9.2) as below:

```js
$scope.mail_notifications = $scope.mail_notifications.filter(x => x["value"]);
```

[Demo @ JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d3uLf620/)

Comment: @Maya, If you think this answer is helpful, you may follow the instruction from [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=To%20accept%20an%20answer%3A,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.). Thanks.